# Laravel scout algolia non object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, algolia, laravel-scout

I'm creating a crud application using laravel and using scout with algolia to perform the search functions.  However, when I perform scout:import "App\Majors" it throws a "trying to get property of non-object" error.  Below is my model.

```
class Major extends Model
{
    use Searchable;

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'album', 'lyrics', 'youtube_link'];

    public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        $genres = array_map(function($item) {
            return trim($item);
        }, explode(',', $this->college->genres));

        return array_merge( $this->toArray(), ['college' => $this->college->name, 'photo' => $this->college->photo, 'genres' => $genres]);
    }

    public function college()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\College');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with `$this->college`. Probably at least one of models does not have college set, and you run:

1. $this->college->genres
2. $this->college->name
3. $this->college->photo

They will all fail, so you should probably secure your code for such cases, for example instead of:

```
explode(',', $this->college->genres)
```

you should use:

```
explode(',', $this->college ? $this->college->genres : '')
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it comes back with "explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given".

Comment: @DamianButtle Sorry for that, obviously `''` should be here instead of `[]` - I've updated my answer